# how would you formulate this sql query?

Tags: sql, oracle, schema

i'm stuck trying to solve the sql query?

List those states that have branch offices but have no customer who have placed orders residing in the state?

### EDIT

```
SELECT branchnumber
  FROM BRANCH
MINUS
SELECT branchnumber
  FROM branch b,
       orders o,
       customer c,
       employee e
  WHERE o.salesperson = e.employeeid AND
        b.branchnumber = e.empbranch AND
        c.customerid = o.customerid AND
        branchstate != c.custstate
```

Tables: https://www.sendspace.com/file/2kfasd

Comment: what have you tried? Post the query that you have written. Also please have a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, to know about how to post a minimal, complete and verifiable example, so that others can help you.

Comment: SELECT branchnumber
FROM BRANCH
MINUS
SELECT branchnumber
FROM branch b, orders o, customer c, employee e                              WHERE o.salesperson = e.employeeid
AND b.branchnumber = e.empbranch                                                        AND c.customerid = o.customerid                                                            AND branchstate != c.custstate

Comment: @helpmesql - don't use comments to add information to the question. You should edit your question (there's an `edit` button right underneath the tags). I've done it this time. Also - don't post links to important information - put that information in the question. Nobody with any sense is going to download your file. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you'd want a WHERE NOT EXISTS rather than MINUS.

```
SELECT DISTINCT B1.BRANCHSTATE
FROM BRANCH b1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 'X'
  FROM branch b2,
       orders o,
       customer c,
       employee e
  WHERE o.salesperson = e.employeeid AND
        b2.branchnumber = e.empbranch AND
        c.customerid = o.customerid AND
        b1.branchstate = c.custstate)
```

EDIT - Your example SQL was pulling BRANCHNAME, but I see your question is asking for states with such branches, so modified to pull distinct STATE.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing about your table structure because I'm not going to download a file of unknown provenance from some file sharing site, but here's a rough guess:

```
SELECT DISTINCT BRANCHSTATE AS STATE
  FROM BRANCH
MINUS
SELECT DISTINCT c.CUSTSTATE AS STATE
  FROM CUSTOMER c
  INNER JOIN ORDERS o
    ON o.CUSTOMERID = c.CUSTOMERID
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Don't think the query can be expressed quite so simplistically.  If branch1 and branch2 are both in NY, and branch2 has customers in NY but branch1 does not - then I think NY should be returned per original spec.

Comment: The first subquery returns all states which have branches. The second query returns all states where customers live who placed orders. Query1 minus query2 returns those states which have branches but have no customers that placed orders, which is what's wanted.

Comment: Ah, right you are - I'd read it (too quickly) as "list all states that have branches that have no customers in their state", clearly it's "list all states that have branches and have no customers".  My original interpretation was influenced by the inclusion of BRANCHES table in pt 2 of OPs sample query; led me to believe OP was aiming for something more intricate.